# How to offset costmap in rviz?

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap, 2dcostmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm running the examples found here: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot

Now, I don't have a turtlebot, so my kinect is placed a lot higher up.
This makes the map visualize pretty weird in rviz (it's floating in mid air).

How do I offset it to say 1m below it's current position on the z-axis?

Do I make a new frame with /base_link or similar as parent and edit a few launch files, if yes, what launch files?
If no, how to move the map?

(Map position is uneditable in rviz)

Let me know if anything was unclear, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233610/how-to-offset-costmap-in-rviz?/) by [TRyKKs](https://answers.ros.org/users/26767/trykks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-07-20**:
Hi! I have the same issue. Have you managed to solve it? I only have one static transform between base_link and camera_link. When I add another between base_link and ground I get and error that my tree is not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without modifying the robot state published by turtlebot launch file, you could add a static transform between the `ground` and `base_footprint`:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="gound_to_base_tf" 
    args="0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /ground /base_footprint 100" />
```

You add this to [demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch) and change `base_footprint` by `ground` for `rtabmap`, `rgbd_odometry` and `rtabmapviz` nodes in the same launch file.

This way, the robot would be 1 meter over the ground, so lowering the map from 1 meter.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-07-20**:
I tried to follow your suggestion but with no success. This is how my [transform tree](https://imgur.com/YoCw8oK) looks with modifications. BTW, Odom is published by Rosaria and it connects to base_link.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-07-23**:
In your case, you cannot do the hack above on your robot, as odometry is already computed accordingly to `base_link`. You may try to make rossaria publishing odom to a `base_footprint` frame that would be on ground under `base_link`, then use `base_footprint` for rtabmap node.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-07-25**:
I did try that afterwards, but it seems like rosaria can only publish to base_link frame. I set base_link_frame parameter as base_footprint but I still get the same warning of two [unconnected trees](https://imgur.com/a/eASNQX5). There is no connection between odom --> base_footprint.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-07-25**:
well, in your tf tree, rossaria doesn't seem to publish any odometry